# Laravel Passport (Api) with Authentication (Google,Facebook)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I am developing an application on Laravel and React. At the moment I made Registration, login through Laravel Passport (API). My task is to make Authentication through Google, Facebook. When you click on the button for the first time, it takes data and fills in for example (email, name, surname) and the user fills in the rest of the fields manually. When the user has already been created. To immediately go to the profile. Can you advise how you can implement this? Thank you.

Comment: Follow this thread - https://medium.com/@hivokas/api-authentication-via-social-networks-for-your-laravel-application-d81cfc185e60